# Receive-Job Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to learn about how to properly use `Receive-Job`. My objective is to essentially have a job start and run something like this:

```
$Alldatasets = [PSCustomobject]@{}

$Alldatasets = if(Test-Path "Alldatasets"){
  Get-ChildItemContent "Alldatasets" | ForEach {$_.Content | Add-Member @{Name = $_.Name} -PassThru} | Where Location -EQ $Location | Where {$Dataset.Count -eq 0 -or (Compare-Object $Dataset $_.Name -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | Measure).Count -gt 0}
}

$Alldatasets
```

Then return the output `$Alldatasets` back to the main script, which you can't see, but would be a table of custom objects.

I understand the process of `receive-job`, but nothing really tutorial-wise how to use it to return the custom object-table that I am making in the above example. Using `wait-job | receive-job`  I get just the actual process details when I use `Get-Member- $Alldatasets` doesn't seem to be anywhere, but running the .ps1 script I wrote it in- It posts `$Alldatasets`. I just can't get `$Alldatasets` from `receive-job`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It wasn't an issue of passing the object. It was an issue of directory.

It doesn't tell you in any of the tutorials I have found, so I will state it here.

`Start-Job` does not specify a location when starting. My above script performed `Test-Path` command with the assumption it was started in the original working directory. I had to specify a working directory in order for script to work:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    param(
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true,
                    Position = 0)]
        $Location,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true,
                    Position = 1)]
        $WorkingDir,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true,
                    Position = 3)]
        $DataSet
    )

    Set-Location "$WorkingDir"
    $Alldatasets = [PSCustomobject]@{}

    $Alldatasets = if(Test-Path "Alldatasets"){
                        Get-ChildItemContent "Alldatasets" | ForEach {$_.Content | Add-Member @{Name = $_.Name} -PassThru} | Where Location -EQ $Location |
                        Where {$Dataset.Count -eq 0 -or (Compare-Object $Dataset $_.Name -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | Measure).Count -gt 0}}

    Return $Alldatasets
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $Location, $DataSet, $WorkingDir -Name "MyCustomJob"
$Alldatasets = Get-Job -Name "MyCustomJob" | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Start-Job` to be able to use 'Receive-Job`. And if you are going to use variables in it, you have to pass it as arguments because you are essentially spinning up a new process/thread and it will not have access to your local variables. Hence the param block.

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    param(
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true,
                    Position = 0)]
        $Location,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true,
                    Position = 1)]
        $DataSet
    )
    $Alldatasets = [PSCustomobject]@{}

    $Alldatasets = if(Test-Path "Alldatasets"){
                        Get-ChildItemContent "Alldatasets" | ForEach {$_.Content | Add-Member @{Name = $_.Name} -PassThru} | Where Location -EQ $Location |
                        Where {$Dataset.Count -eq 0 -or (Compare-Object $Dataset $_.Name -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | Measure).Count -gt 0}}

    Return $Alldatasets
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $Location, $DataSet -Name "MyCustomJob"
$Alldatasets = Get-Job -Name "MyCustomJob" | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: I am. So if I run it like this- If I get-member $AllDataSets, I should be able to find $Alldataset? Because I don't see it when the job completes. But when I paste this script into a .ps1 file and run i separately- I see it is creating it. I just can't get is as I run it as a job, wait-job, receive job.

However, when I run it as a job, and try to receive $Alldatasets, then $Alldatasets | Get-Member nothing is there but the job information. I am trying to do it how you are writing it, actually. Very close.

Comment: But you partially answered my question. In theory, I can have it return $Allldatasets receive job. I just need to figure out how. Tutorials say nothing about being about get get custom objects